# A class that are got instance once by two different application

Tags: c#, class, oop, constructor, static-constructor

I created a class for authentication of my project.

I want to use it in my website and also in mobile application but why this class has a static constructor and should be get instance one time, it didn't work well, I mean I want to get instance for each application once.

I want to know how fix it?

Comment: You wish the static class to be initialized once in each of the applications? Show some code and if possible a snippet that reproduces the problem.

Comment: You so understand that separate processes will have separate copies of static fields, etc, right?

Comment: static is class level not instance level.check the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're looking for a singleton pattern.

> "I mean I want to get instance for each application once."

I assume you mean that you want to construct an instance once per application.

The easiest implementation is to use this:

```
public class MyAuth
{
    private static readonly MyAuth instance = new MyAuth();
    public static MyAuth Instance { get { return instance; } }

    private MyAuth()
    {
        // initialization goes here and will be called once
    }

    // Members. 
}
```

So first off, I'm not sure if this is a good solution. Authorization is usually updated from different applications, so it might be better to flush the authentication once in a while.

Second, note that member functions can be called from multiple threads. If you want to do it like this, you have to use locking for fields that you use (either directly or indirectly). Be sure to know what you're doing.

There is an alternative solution that solves all this in a neat way (and a ton of other issues). It's called a database; you might want to consider using that.

Comment: Thanks so much , I will check the application Authorization  again , i think i didn't describe our problem properly, and also i will try the singleton pattern, it sounds good way to select in this case